# Exception print in logs if I am handling error in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

---

Hi my code is here

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from Exception, :with => :error_render_method

   def error_render_method
    respond_to do |type|
      type.html { render :template => "web/static/missing", :status => 404 }
      type.all  { render :nothing => true, :status => 404 }
    end
    true
  end
end
```

Its working fine but i want to also print in logs if any error occurred how can i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`logger.warn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html):

```
rescue_from Exception do |exception|
   error_render_method(exception)
end

def error_render_method(error)
  logger.warn(error.message)
  respond_to do |type|
    type.html { render :template => "web/static/missing", :status => 404 }
    type.all  { render :nothing => true, :status => 404 }
  end
  true
end
```